# jQuery replace text of element with another element value

Tags: jquery

let's say that i have two inputs, the first one is for amount, and the second one is for price
if the user changed the amount, the price should be change to amount*price

```
<input type='text' name='amount' />
<input type='text' name='price' />
```

there is already PHP variable that has the price !

how can i do that ?

Comment: `amount*price` where do you want to display this..?

Answer (score 1):

I just presumed that you are going to display the result in a `readonly` text box,

HTML,

```
<input type='text' name='amount' />
<input type='text' name='price' />
<input type='text' name='result' readonly=true/>
```

JS,

```
  var amt = $('input[name=amount]')
  var price = $('input[name=price]')

  amt.add(price).on('input', function () {
      var amtVal = parseInt(amt.val(), 10);
      var priceVal = parseInt(price.val(), 10);
      $('[name=result]').val((isNaN(amtVal) ? 0 : amtVal) * (isNaN(priceVal) ? 0 : priceVal));
  });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8338N/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E8jhv/2/)**

Try the following snippet,

```
$('input[name=amount]').keyup(function () {
    var value = isNaN(this.value) ? false : parseFloat(this.value);


        $('input[name=price]').val(function () {
            if (value && this.value.length) {
                return isNaN(this.value) ? '' : parseFloat(this.value) * value;
            }
        });

});
```

You can use `change` instead of `keyup`. Also I suppose all the involved elements are static.

Comment: +1 for using the parsefloat.. I didn't think of that..